# Seaborn: How to specify plot minor ticks and gridlines in all plots when using lmplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, lmplot

I'm trying to get minor ticks and gridlines plotted in all plots when using lmplot, using the code below:

```
sns.set(context="notebook", style='white', font_scale=2)

g=sns.lmplot(data=data ,
             x="x", 
             y="y",
             col="item",   # or use rows to display xplots in rows (one on top of the other)
             fit_reg=False,
             col_wrap=2,
             scatter_kws={'linewidths':1,'edgecolor':'black', 's':100}
            )

g.set(xscale='linear', yscale='log', xlim=(0,0.4), ylim=(0.01, 10000))

for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', direction='out', length=4, left=True)
    ax.grid(b=True, which='both', color='gray', linewidth=0.1)
    
for axis in [ax.yaxis, ax.xaxis]:
    formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.16g}'.format(y))
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

sns.despine()

g.tight_layout()

# Show the results
plt.show()
```

So far, only major ticks and gridlines are shwon in all plots.

Thanks for any advice for solving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code work fine for me.
I think the problem is that when the major labels are too big, matplotlib chooses not to display the minor ticks, and hence the minor grid lines. You may either change `font_scale`, or increase the size of your figure (see `height=` in `lmplot()`)

Consider the following code with `font_scale=1`

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

sns.set(context="notebook", style='white', font_scale=1)
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", col="day", hue="day",
               data=tips, col_wrap=2, height=3)

g.set(xscale='linear', yscale='log')
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', direction='out', length=4, left=True)
    ax.grid(b=True, which='both', color='gray', linewidth=0.1)
    
for axis in [ax.yaxis, ax.xaxis]:
    formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.16g}'.format(y))
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

sns.despine()

g.tight_layout()

# Show the results
plt.show()
```

[image]

compare with the result using `font_scale=2`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Diziet Asahi, it works now. Thank you for your detailed explanation